# No route matches [POST] "/" only in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using Simple Form For, I have created a custom auth system.

routes.rb

```
get '/users/sign_in' => 'sessions#new', as: :sessions_new_user
post '/users/sign_in' => 'sessions#create', as: :sessions_create_user
match '/users/sign_out' => 'sessions#destroy', as: :sessions_destroy_user, via: :delete
get '/users/process_login' => 'sessions#process_login', as: :sessions_process_login
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for :user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :login, placeholder: "Login", label_html: { class: 'form-control' }%>
  <%= f.input :password, label_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'  %>
<% end %>
```

This issue is when i run the tests to simulate a sign in, I get this error.

```
user visits root of application
     Failure/Error: click_on 'Log in'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [POST] "/"
```

user_spec.rb

```
scenario 'user visits root of application' do
  visit root_path

  expect(page).to have_content("Sign in to continue")

  fill_in ' Login', with: ENV['NTUSERNAME']
  fill_in ' Password', with: ENV['NTPASSWORD']
  click_on 'Log in'
end
```

This works fine in development. I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are learning Rails I'd recommend you start out with the simple [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), as you can more clearly define what you're looking for. Since you are not using RESTful routes, you'll have to define everything by hand and are really missing out on Rails's approach of convention over configuration.

However, if you really want to make Simple Form work, here's how you would do it:

```
<%= simple_form_for :user,  url: sessions_create_user, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :login, placeholder: "Login", label_html: { class: 'form-control' }%>
  <%= f.input :password, label_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'  %>
<% end %>
```

Also be aware that since you are not using an ActiveRecord-backed object (just a label), you'll have to be careful to match your expected `params` to what Simple Form is sending in. I'm also curious as to how you have SF render out the correct action path for a user session in development without specifying it out...

Comment: you forgot `_path` at end of `url` key and i do not see an answer, _why this works in development and not in test?_

Comment: Thanks for the insights guys. I ended up removing the simple_form alltogether to discover my real issue. There was a nested <form> tag in the code. It was over riding the test. 

The reason for the custom routes... well, my auth system relies on them. not my rules.

Answer (score 1):

because `simple_form_for` don't have `url`, it will use the current url to submit data

Not tested but I think as below:

In development, when you visit `root`, it will redirect to `/users/sign_in`, posting to `/users/sign_in` is acceptable

In rspec, redirecting not change the current url, it still `root_path`, so posting to `/` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

##### Nested forms are not allowed...

I had accidentally nested a form tag with an action of "#". It all worked in development as the browser spotted it was a nested form, and it was ignoring the tag. But when I ran a rack test it failed with `No route matches [POST] “/”` - it also did work when I used JS/selenium test as it was being run in a real browser.

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <form action="#" method="POST">    
    <%= f.input :login %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>    
  </form>
<% end %>
```